# Does the Git Jenkins plug-in support variables for repository URLs?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm basically wondering if, in a Jenkins project configuration, one can refer to a variable for the Git plug-in's *URL of repository* field. For example: $MY_REPO.

Comment: This means, you really dont know, where your repository is?! O_o

Comment: lol @KingCrunch, I think he means he can check out of multiple repositories, but he would like to pick one

Comment: I know it works for the Subversion plugin, so my guess would be yes; however, I do not have access to a git repo so I cannot answer your question. However, why not try it?

Comment: @Sagar: I tried the $MY_REPO form, but it makes the plug-in raise an exception (how charming) :) I seem to recall I've made this work in the past..

Comment: $MY_REPO form? The way I made it work was to use a Jenkins parameter (CHOICE). May be the git plugin has not implemented variables. You could file a bug at http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: @Sagar: By form I was referring to the variable syntax :) Defining the variable itself is no problem.

Comment: Oh...try ${MY_REPO}, with the braces I mean

Comment: @Sagar: that's what I tried first :)

Comment: Oh...oops lol, never mind then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can conclude that it is not supported in the current version of the plug-in, particularly as a request for this functionality has been filed in Jenkins' bug tracker.

Comment: do you know the ticket number?

Comment: @ValdisR I can't recall the ticket number sorry, but it appears the problem has been fixed in Git plugin 1.1.15.